# Angular Ng-Table Sort & Pagination

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ngtable

I am having trouble sorting with Ng-table and including pagination to js. Will my `angular.module` pass as shown?

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', 
['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http, $filter, ngTableParams)
{
    var data = $scope.stuff = {
    "Monday": [{
        "Name": "John",
        "Address": "Street",
        "Phone": "111",
        "Status": "Sleep",
        "Kids":"3 Kids"
},......
```

Here's [a link](http://plnkr.co/edit/NT3c7XRS6Plh3nEYZWx8?p=preview). Search Monday & Tuesday values.

Comment: you are inject thing and expecting 4 objects.. i doubt your plunker does even compile

Comment: Ok.  So to fix this do you think I need to place the ng-table in a separate controller?  The plunker works just not sorting.  Thanks.

Comment: no.. please go ahead and do some basic example of angular. the basic things you are doing are wrong. so please learn those first.. use egghead.io videos

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I've been through basic angular examples and the videos on egghead that I need to see are not free.  I'll continue working with the module parameters.